# Custom google maps style takes a second to load

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3

I'm implementing a custom style for my google maps view for a bus transit app I'm developing in XCode 9 w/ Swift 4. Whenever I load a map view, it always takes a little less than a second to load the custom style and I'm not sure what's causing this to happen.

Here's the effect I'm describing:

[image]

As you can see, the tan background is the default style for google's mapview, and it's visible for only a small period of time.

Here's my code that implements the map view:

```
class StopPredictionVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setUpMapView()
    }

    private func setUpMapView() {
        let stopLatitude = Double(stop!.lat)
        let stopLongitude = Double(stop!.lon)

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: stopLatitude!, longitude: stopLongitude!, zoom: 16.4)
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: frame, camera: camera)

        let nightModeEnabled = APIWrapper.sharedInstance.settings.nightMode!

        if nightModeEnabled {
            mapView.mapStyle(withFilename: "nightStyle", andType: "json")
        } else {
            mapView.mapStyle(withFilename: "mapStyle", andType: "json")
        }

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker")
        marker.appearAnimation = .pop
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: stopLatitude!, longitude: stopLongitude!)
        marker.title = "Bus Stop Name"
        marker.snippet = "Example description"
        marker.map = mapView

        buildRoute(routePath: routeConfig!.path)

        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}

extension GMSMapView {
    func mapStyle(withFilename name: String, andType type: String) {
        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: type) {
                self.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

`buildRoute(routePath:)` is a function that builds the blue colored path on the road if anyone was wondering.

Obviously this isn't a huge bug, but it's quite frustrating to see every time I load a map view. Anyone see anything in my code that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call it inside `viewWillAppear` it has 2 problems , first it's called after viewDidLoad (has some delay) , second it may be called every time the VC is shown such as returning from a push / dismiss Modal

so call `setUpMapView` inside `viewDidLoad`

note this `buildRoute(routePath: routeConfig!.path)` should be in a background queue if it calls any web service or do any long job inside mainQueue

BTW i may also try to load

```
GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
```

in background thread and after load set in mainQueue and that only if using `GMSMapStyle` is allowed inside a back thread